# Best practice to implement blank tile search to anagram solver

Tags: php, anagram

I currently have an anagram solver on my website that works well and quickly.

I use an array structure to hold number values of each letter used in each word. So basically when someone put in the letters "fghdywkjd" My solver will go through each word in its db and match the amout of letters in each word to the values associated with the letter inputted ie. "fghdywkjd"

I build the array like this

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 1, 'd' => 1, 'e' => 1, 'f' => 1, 'g' => 1, 'h' => 1, 'i' => 1, 'j' => 1, 'k' => 1, 'l' => 1, 'm' => 1, 'n' => 1, 'o' => 1, 'p' => 1, 'q' => 1, 'r' => 1, 's' => 1, 't' => 1, 'u' => 1, 'v' => 1, 'w' => 1, 'x' => 1, 'y' => 1, 'z' => 1);
```

It counts the values as it goes through each word.

I am trying to think of the best way to add a blank tile feature to it that is not going to slow it down.

The only way I can figure out how to add this feature is to wait till I have all my results then take each word found and add the letter "a" and find possibilities, then add the latter "b" and so on. For each word that would be enormous.

Anyways some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's probably how I would do it.  I would set up the word database table structure like this: (The main reason for this is speed. We could split the names by letter each query but I think this way is faster though I haven't benchmarked).

```
name    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
----    -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
test    0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
tests   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
foo     0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

and then in the PHP I'd do this: This assumes that the number of letters in the word has to match the anagram exactly (no extra letters).

```
<?php
$letters = array_fill_keys (range('a', 'z'), 0);

$word = 'set'; // start with the word 'set'
$wordLetters = str_split(preg_replace("/[^a-z]/", '', strtolower($word))); // remove invalid letters, lowercase, and convert to array

$numberOfWildcards = 1; // Change this to the number of wildcards you want

foreach ($wordLetters as $letter) {
    $letters[$letter]++;
}

$query = 'SELECT `name`, 0';

foreach ($letters as $letter => $num) {
    // $query .= "+ABS(`$letter`-$num)";
    $query .= "+IF(`$letter` > $num, `$letter` - $num, 0)";
}

$query = ' AS difference
    FROM `word_table`
    WHERE 
        LENGTH(`name`) = ' . (strlen($word) + $numberOfWildcards) . '
    HAVING
        difference = ' . $numberOfWildcards;
```

If you want to see the difference between the word you are checking and all the words in the database get rid of the where and having clauses.

Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: Great minds think alike :) My table structure is exactly that :) I implimented your code with a little fix .= instead of just =. Using word set worked perfect except it only pulls the possible words with SET in it plus one more so it was only 4 letter words. What about pulling every possible word "SET" can make along with addition wild card words?

Comment: this would include 2 through 12 letter words btw

Comment: It may work for you to change the $numberOfWildcards to $maxWildcards and then change the WHERE and HAVING to be `<=` instead of `=`

Comment: that helped in some cases, but not all. For instance go to my site http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com and enter the letters "settingz" I can get 111 words total from those letters. With the script above it is only getting 3 words ('SETTING','TESTING','ZESTING'). Im not understanding if the ABS has anything to do with it, but why is the ABS listed with a negative number. Doesn't it not matter whether positive or negative since its absolute either way?

Comment: ok I think I am understanding more now, I think the issue it the "difference = 1" Since I use the letters "settingz" it is looking for words that contain all but at least 1 letter difference. "SETTING" has a difference of 1. Since there is no word that can be created with a difference of 0 it is not listing any. So the issue is that it must contain "AT LEAST" ANY of the letters. Not MUST contain every letter. Make sense? Sorry I type as I think LOL. Ill mess with it more. Any input would be awesome...

Comment: OK tried "+ABS(`$letter`-$num)" to "|ABS(`$letter`-$num)" and that definitely didn't work LOL. I think the issue is in the "+" for the ABS but I am not sure how to specify that the word must contain any of the letters, not all but at least any of the letter and on top of that the difference applies as well.

Comment: @CesarBielich Why don't you atleast upvote this answer ? He has put some efforts in it.

Comment: I added if ($num != 0) {$query .= "+ABS(`$letter`-$num)";} thinking maybe that would only use the letters that were in the word to begin with. So it does not use any with a $num that = 0. But that didnt work either. Thanks so much for all the help BTW :)

Comment: What also confuses me is why are you subtracting a letter from a number in +ABS(`$letter`-$num)? Im not even sure how that works or why the sql even works :)

Comment: The subtract is saying take the number of letter A's from the row and subtract that from the number of letter A's from the word. So if the database row has 3 A's and the word we're checking has 2 then 3 - 2 = 1 There is one difference in the amount of letter A's between the two.   The reason I have an absolute value is if the word we are checking has 3 letter A's and the database row has 2 then 2 - 3 = -1 and that would mess up the difference. The difference in the number of letter A's is still 1.  What we need to do is instead of converting -1 to 1 we need to convert it to 0.

Comment: @CesarBielich I changed the `ABS` part to `$query .= "+IF(`$letter` > $num, `$letter` - $num, 0)";` Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I <3 u...that worked :) Can I give you 100,000,000,000,000 points? Maybe they will let me